# Neural Network is getting worse over more Iterations

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, deep-learning, data-science

We are currently working on a project that involves Neural Networks. Our task consists of upscaling an 16x16 image all the way up to a picture with the resolution of 64x64. We have already written the code and aquired a reasonably large dataset consisting of 200.000 images, which we have already organized into arrays of a thousand pictures, with 1.npy being our X values and 88.npy being our Y values. Since we tried implementing our network with as few libraries as possible, we are experiencing a weird bug in our code. Instead of improving over time it seems to get worse as the iterations pass, with the predicted values reaching almost the millions instead of stabilizing around 0 to 255. We are by no means expert's on the topic and would be happy, if someone pointed out some mistakes we made in our implementation. There are quite a few comments in our code to help you guys figure out what we have done. Furthermore we also provided a drawn picture of our model along with the two arrays consisting of a thousand pictures each. Feel free to ask us as many questions as you want. If you want run the code on your own conmputer here is a link to download all files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zSnCRhkwAZOze_ZjabjoVhOhTJufHfoB?usp=sharing

Greetings from Germany,
Armin

We have basicly only tried:

1. Adjusting the learning rate
2. Increased the number of neurons in each layer
3. Played around with some of the shapes

```py
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np

X = np.load('1.npy')  # X values, X.shape = (768,1000) (16*16*3 Input features and 1000 trainingsexamples)
Y = np.load('88.npy')  # Y values, Y.shape = (12288,1000) (64*64*3 Output features and 1000 trainingsexamples)
m = 1000  # Number of the trainingsexamples
alpha = 0.05  # Learning rate
iterations = 1000
cache = 0  # Used to save our previous J to calculate if we are getting better or not

# Definiton of our NN modell

# First layer / first hidden layer
W_1 = np.random.randn(768, 4)  # weights
B_1 = np.zeros((4, 1))
Z_1 = np.zeros((4, 1000))
A_1 = np.zeros((4, 1000))  # Activations of the first layer

# Second layer / second hidden layer
W_2 = np.random.randn(4, 5)
B_2 = np.zeros((5, 1))
Z_2 = np.zeros((5, 1000))
A_2 = np.zeros((5, 1000))

# Third layer/ output layer
W_3 = np.random.randn(5, 12288)
B_3 = np.zeros((12288, 1))
Z_3 = np.zeros((12288, 1000))
A_3 = np.zeros((12288, 1000))

for i in range(iterations):

    # Forwardprop start
    Z_1 = np.dot(W_1.T, X) + B_1
    A_1 = np.maximum(Z_1, 0)

    Z_2 = np.dot(W_2.T, A_1) + B_2
    A_2 = np.maximum(Z_2, 0)

    Z_3 = np.dot(W_3.T, A_2) + B_3
    A_3 = np.maximum(Z_3, 0)

    # Calculates the loss and shows, if the NN is getting better or not
    Loss = np.square(Y - A_3)
    J = Loss.mean()
    if J < cache:
        print('smaller')
    else:
        print('bigger')
    cache = J
    # Forwardprop End

    # BackProp Start
    da_dz = Z_3 >= 0  # da_dz = da/dz
    da_dz = da_dz.astype(np.int)
    dZ_3 = -2 * (A_3 - Y) * da_dz  # dZ_3 = dL(Y, A_3)/dZ_3
    dW_3 = np.dot(dZ_3, A_2.T) * (1 / m)  # dW_3 = dL(Y, A_3)/dW_3
    dB_3 = np.sum(dZ_3, axis=1, keepdims=True) * (1 / m)  # dB_3 = dL(Y, A_3)/dB_3

    # Gradient descent
    W_3 = W_3 - alpha * dW_3.T
    B_3 = B_3 - alpha * dB_3

    da_dz = Z_2 >= 0
    da_dz = da_dz.astype(np.int)
    dZ_2 = np.dot(dW_3.T, dZ_3) * da_dz
    dW_2 = np.dot(dZ_2, A_1.T) * (1 / m)
    dB_2 = (np.sum(dZ_2, axis=1, keepdims=True)) * (1 / m)

    W_2 = W_2 - alpha * dW_2.T
    B_2 = B_2 - alpha * dB_2

    da_dz = Z_1 >= 0
    da_dz = da_dz.astype(np.int)
    dZ_1 = np.dot(dW_2.T, dZ_2) * da_dz
    dW_1 = np.dot(dZ_1, X.T) * (1 / m)
    dB_1 = (np.sum(dZ_1, axis=1, keepdims=True)) * (1 / m)

    W_1 = W_1 - alpha * dW_1.T
    B_1 = B_1 - alpha * dB_1
    # BackProp End
    print(i)
```

Comment: Haven't looked in detail into this but one observation: 1. if `A_3 - Y` is positive, weights should decrease (we are overpredicting). 2. `dZ_3` then is negative, hence `dW_3` is negative, hence `(- alpha * dW_3.T)` is positive. Which means that `W_3` increases.
Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes it works the loss gets smaller and smaller 

Comment: So that was the issue?

Comment: Yes thank you ver much :). 
Is there anything left to do with this post? I am new on stack overflow.

Comment: Well, this is freaking amazing :) Happy that it works!
As for the post, I don't think the answer would be very useful to others, so let's leave it as it is :)